# Site does not respond equal with web browser or with curl

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, session-cookies

I'm want practise programming making a simple application that HTTP Request a site to get the price of an hotel. I'm going to travel this summer and I want to know the min price in this propper 2 months.

I want to capture the price of an hotel in booking.com. When I use a web browser, I see the price but when I use PHP cUrl the site does not respond with same HTML data. With cUrl I'm not able to see the price of the hotel.

I suspect that the problem may be session or cookies. I have tried for 2 weeks but I can't solve it.

The url is http://www.booking.com/hotel/us/blakely-new-york.es.html?aid=356984;label=gog235jc-district-es-us-newNyork_manhattan-unspec-es-com;sid=f44e42aec5d1476017c8ab1841371d7b;dcid=1;checkin=2014-05-04;checkout=2014-05-10;srfid=d06488818183ccefd944221a0e84c2e00d121135X20

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: curl will get the html returned by the site, but it won't execute any javascript for you if the site content is built by ajax calls

Comment: Are you saving cookies with curl ? booking.com relies on it.

Comment: I don't know how to do this...perhaps cookies are the problem... i have tried with file_get_contents, with basic curl and  simple_html_dom but I always get the same html without prices.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so straigthforward with booking.com. To retrieve information from Booking.com, you should [become an affiliate partner](http://www.booking.com/content/affiliate-help.en-us.html?aid=357006;label=gog235jc-content-XX-affiliatehelp-XX-unspec-gr-com;sid=7b983be892b99783f5ba77d97c41b555;dcid=1;tmpl=docs/partners_affiliate_help) of them so you can be granted access to their API. Then, use the API to get any information you need from their site.

Comment: Thank you Aggelos! I just want it to know one price. Perhaps booking.com doesn't give me an access to API to do this. What do you think?

Comment: I think that booking.com won't give you access to their API only for a single price. So... if it is one-time solution, you can use simple dom parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to get all the elements of the html page and find the one with the price.

Comment: I have tried with that class last week but I think booking detects I'm a "bot" and don't show prices on the html I get.

Comment: yes, the problem is not the parsing, but you do not even get the site you requested, when using cURL